Is there a way to hide several year old questions?
I have been getting back into the habit of checking this forum, trying to help others with what little I can. However, I'm noticing a not insignificant trend when loading the home page; I'm seeing posts from at least two years ago popping up at the top.
I have been noticing these questions at the top of the list because someone decided to edit them just an hour ago (give or take). Now, I feel conflicted by two rules I've come across online; on the one hand, we want our questions and answers to be easily read and understood. On the other hand, I've noticed a lot of online communities frown upon "necro-posting"; where a "long dead" thread is suddenly revived by someone who arrives ages later to post a (usually unhelpful) reply.
I was wondering if there was a way to filter posts strictly by post date, not activity, so I can avoid necro-posting on these questions? Maybe I've accidentally glossed over the option.

This community's model is to keep older posts up to date so they stay relevant, but that also includes maintennance-style edits (grammar, formatting, modifying tags etc) which don't necessarily add anything "new" from a content perspective. We're closer to Wikipedia, than Reddit or a forum, in that regard.

Stop thinking Super User as a forum, once you do, you realize older questions are positive not negative

@Robotnik we even had a lovely venn diagram for that!

Don't use the front page - there's a newest question view that should do what you want
Questions tab on the left, 'newest' on top tab once you have, rather than the front page.

That said, both bumps of old posts (by the system), and updated answers to old questions is part of the model here - we don't just want to help the person asking a question but future people with similar issues, and there's value on necroposting.
Also, - a common pet pedantic peeve. this isn't a forum, its a Q&A site
